# Hot to get current user from firebase to javaMailAPI

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, gmail

I'm developing hospital app management system in which Everytime user make appointment doctor gets email.

For signing in i use firebase AuthUI
Now i made onclick listener and put all the code of javaMailAPI in it. The problem is that i want the current user from firebase to send email transparently without intent. Without providing the email and password in the code like javaMailAPI.
Please help

Comment: That's not going to be possible using only client code.  Firebase doesn't offer any generalized email sending services that work with Firebase Auth.  You will need to route the request through a backend that manages the connection to the SMTP server.

Comment: I'm thinking to use twilio is that good?

Comment: Recommendations for off-site resources are off topic for Stack Overflow.  I'm sure there is a general discussion group where you could get some advice.